# Add HTML5 tags to XHTML field formating

Tags: custom-fields, formatting

It looks like the «xhtml»-field-formating in EE 2.5.5 has problems with figure and figcaption. If I write…

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.

<figure class="quote"><blockquote>bla bla bla</blockquote><figcaption>Willhelm Tell</figcaption></figure>

Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

… into a custom field with xhtml-field-formatting, the following will be rendered:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p><figure class="quote"><blockquote><p>bla bla bla</p>
</blockquote><p></p><figcaption><p></p><p>Willhelm Tell</p><p></p></figcaption><p></p><p></p></figure><p></p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
```

which obviously is everything else than «optimal» ;-)

How can I tell EE to ignore figcaption and figure in «xhtml»-field-formating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that this is actually inside CodeIgniter.

To add new HTML5 tags like `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` to the list of « do not wrap with `<p>` tags», just add them to the array located ~ line 30 of **/system/codeigniter/system/libraries/Typography.php** (the arrays `$block_elements` and/or `$skip_elements`).

I've also added an [EE Bug Report for this](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19112). The new tags should hopefully be included into future EE releases.

Comment: Please improve your answer by being more specific about *what* you found and how you actually fixed this problem. It will help other folks out more. Then you can mark it as the accepted answer in a couple of days.

Comment: @DerekHogue done